# Draw curved line between two points

Tags: java, draw, curve, bezier

I can't even remember since when I've been looking for a way to draw a curved line between two points.

I've tried many things like `QuadCurves2D`, Bezier Curve, etc..., but I'm failing to find a control point.

The idea here is to draw a curved line between two points independently where they are or which angle between them(user can change the points' position by clicking alt and dragging it over the screen)

This is what I've got so far...
[image: Wrong curve between two points]

As you can see above, the curve is absolutely wrong.

What I expect is something like this:

[image: Correct curve]

Comment: Two points only define a line. If you want a smooth curve, you need more than two points to define it.

Comment: @duskwuff I see.. But what I'm trying to understand is exactly what you're saying. I want to find a Control Point between these two points so I can have a curved line.

Comment: You need to choose the control point! Consider the two lines you have between 0 and 5 — how is your program supposed to decide which of the two to draw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step one: axis-align your two points so that one of them's on (0,0), and the other's on ([...],0). Let's say we have two points,

```
P1 = {a,b)
P2 = {c,d}
```

we translate them so that p1's on 0,0:

```
P1 = {0,0}
P2 = {c-a,d-b}
```

then we rotate p2 about (0,0) so that it ends up lying on the x-axis:

```
a = -atan2(dy,dx) = -atan2(d-b, c-a)
P2ʹ = {
  p2.x * cos(a) - p2.y * sin(a),
  p2.x * sin(a) + p2.y * cos(a)
}
```

note the - in front of the `atan2` call because we don't want to know the angle "from axis to point", but from point to x-axis. We now have two axis-aligned points (let's call that rotated x-coordinate for the new P2 "v"):

```
P1  = { 0 , 0 }
P2ʹ = { v , 0 }
```

We can now do whatever we want in terms of curve construction. While usually pretty ugly, we can construct a quadratic curve with a control point that's at `(v/2, ...)` and has a height "whatever you want based on how strong you want the curvature to be. This will give us a coordinate relative to the transform-invariant coordinates, so we just apply the rotation/translation in reverse:

```
C  = (v/2,h), then rotate by -a, then translate by (a,b)
```

(note that - sign again). We already know where P1 and P2 were, so we don't need to do any computing there. Bezier curves are defined by their "hull points" and well-behaved with regards to linear transformations so all this translation/rotation business makes not difference to the algorithm that draws the curves. Just plug the six values into the quadratic draw functions and presto. A curve from P1 to P2 controlled by C.

Of course you probably want a cubic curve instead because quadratic curves are quite ugly, so instead of defining a C, we can define a C1 and C2:

```
C1 = (v/3, 0)
C2 = (2*v/3, 0)
```

and then raise/lower them both by the same amount; then we anti-rotate and anti-translate them and plug the P1, C1, C2, P2 we now have into a cubic bezier drawing function: done. Pretty curves.

Comment: Thank you for your very well constructed answer, Mike.
I'm going to implement your suggestion I will be back soon to check your answer as correct.

Comment: @GabrielCâmara Looks like you never did.

Comment: @Tara I didn't have much time, so I had to drop the project. Too bad, it was awesome back in time.

Comment: As long as a post answered the question, even if you no longer work on it, remember to accept it so that future visitors benefit from finding it in web searches. "Unanswered" questions do not get pushed to the surface.

Comment: @GabrielCâmara I think it's basic courtesy (and how this site works) to reward a user by accepting their answer, as they spent time out of their own busy life to help you.

Comment: You're both right @Tara and Mike, but since I couldn't really try the solution above, I felt like I would be misguiding those who are looking for an answer. How could I possibly mark as the correct answer if I haven't tried on my old code? That was my thought. Anyhow, I'll mark as correct, since your arguments seem about right to me. Sorry I took so long to accept this answer, and thank you for your time Mike

Comment: I checked this answer using python. The logic definitely works.